# How To Set Config For image in Subdomains in opencart 2.3.0.2?

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I want to load images for subdomain with image folder of main domain.

Main domain name is example: `MainDomain`

and Subdomain is example: `Max88`

Address of image in main domain is:

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/image/');
```

and This is Config of my subdomain:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://MainDomain.com/Max88/');
//define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.MainDomain.com/');


// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://MainDomain.com/Max88/');
//define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.MainDomain.com/');


// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/');
//define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/image/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/upload/');
```

Set     `define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/image/');`

But Not load Image for Subdomain.

in Home page
Address of image is:

```
   src="http://MainDomain.com/Max88/image/cache/catalog/S/x.jpg"
```

when Edit and delete Max88 load image.
please help me.

Comment: Please Help me!!!

Comment: have you changes in both config.php file?

Comment: yes my friend....

Comment: no answer for my question?